# Code Unreachable detected C# in listner.Close();

Tags: c#

Here is the Code
Well there's a problem in `listener.Close();`

Why is it unreachable?

I have a client and server and the client is going to submit results to the server using an array

Everything is done in the while(true)

```
public void listen()
{

    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2112));
    listener.Listen(10);

    while (true) {
        Socket socket = listener.Accept();
        string receivedValue = string.Empty;
        while (true) {
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes);


            receivedValue += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, numBytes);

            if (receivedValue.IndexOf("[ ]") > -1)
            {
                break;
            }  

             string replyValue1 =string.Empty;
             string replyValue2 = string.Empty;
             string replyValue3 = string.Empty;
             string replyValue4 = string.Empty;
             string replyValue5 = string.Empty;
             string replyValue6 = string.Empty;

             string[] answers = receivedValue.Split(',');

            cAns1 = Convert.ToInt32(answers[1]);
            cAns2 = Convert.ToInt32(answers[2]);
            cAns3 = Convert.ToInt32(answers[3]);
            cAns4 = Convert.ToInt32(answers[4]);
            cAns5 = Convert.ToInt32(answers[5]);
            cAns6 = Convert.ToInt32(answers[6]);
            if (ans1 == cAns1)
                replyValue1 = "Correct";
            else
                replyValue1 = "Incorrect";
            if (ans2 == cAns2)
                replyValue2 = "Correct";
            else
                replyValue2 = "Incorrect";
            if (ans3 == cAns3)
                replyValue3 = "Correct";
            else
                replyValue3 = "Incorrect";
            if (ans4 == cAns4)
                replyValue4 = "Correct";
            else
                replyValue4 = "Incorrect";
            if (ans5 == cAns5)
                replyValue5 = "Correct";
            else
                replyValue5 = "Incorrect";
            if (ans6 == cAns6)
                replyValue6 = "Correct";
            else
                replyValue6 = "Incorrect";

            string replyMsg= replyValue1+","+replyValue2+","+replyValue3+","+replyValue4+","+replyValue5+","+replyValue6;
            byte[] replyingMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(replyMsg + "[ ]");
            socket.Send(replyingMsg);

            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();

        }

  }
    listener.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because you have infinite outer loop `while (true)`. Your `break` operator breaks inner loop only. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx):

> The break statement terminates the **closest enclosing loop** or switch
>   statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that
>   follows the terminated statement, if any.

Simplified your code looks like:

```
while (true) // this infinite loop is not terminated
{            
     while (true) // this is a closest enclosing loop
     {
         if (condition)
         {
              break; // this breaks inner loop only
         }  
     }
} // you are not exiting this loop, so further lines are unreachable       

listener.Close();
```

Comment: @user3210456 depends on what you want to do. I suggest you to remove outer loop

Comment: You must provide some way to break out of the outer `while` loop.

Comment: @mattm I really don't see why outer loop needed. Looks like it simply can be removed in this case

Comment: @Sergey- I agree, just informing OP what he needs to do in case he wants to keep it for some reason.